# How to calculate the analytical result of this singular integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve this integral:

$I(a,b)=\displaystyle{\int_1^{\infty }\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{\sqrt{x^2-1} (1+x\sqrt{1-b^2}) (x-1/\sqrt{1-b^2})} \, dx} \,\, \,\,(a \;\textrm{real>0} \, , 0<b<1)$

by varying b from 0 to 1.

Mathematica didn't calculate this integral. Maybe it is too complicated to be done.

In Mathematica input form:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x]/(Sqrt[x^2 - 1](1+x Sqrt[1-b^2])(x-(1/Sqrt[1-b^2]))), {x,1,Infinity}]
```

If I simply enter that into Mathematica, it instantly returns the same expression. 
How do I go about this? Is there any tricks that can be applied?
Is there a way to get the a symbolic result?

Thank's.

Comment: No real comment

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch no b>0

Comment: note he wants 0<b<1, which is where the singularity pops up (at x=1/Sqrt[1-b^2]) .  Do we have some reason to think this is convergent when `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` say it is not?

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59206/7167) about the same integral?

Comment: @betatron Yes, I realized this.

Comment: I noticed that the substitution $x = \cosh(t)$, $dx = \sinh(t) dt$, $\cosh(t)^2 - \sinh(t)^2 = 1$ transforms the integrand into a simpler form. However, this transformation doesn't seem to get you any closer to a closed-form solution to the integral, and you also need to know which way to go around the pole on the real line.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a way to integrate it symbolically, but here is a way to approximate it:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{a, b, Im@NIntegrate[ Exp[-a x]/(Sqrt[x^2 - 1] 
                            (1 + x Sqrt[1 - b^2]) (x - (1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]))),
                                        {x, 1, Infinity}]},
                     {a, 1, 20, .5}, {b, 2, 20, .5}], 1];
model = k2 Exp[-k3 a] Exp[-k4 b];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {k2, k3, k4}, {a, b}];
modelf = Function[{a, b}, Evaluate[model /. fit]];
Show[Plot3D[modelf[a, b], {a, 1, 20}, {b, 2, 20}, PlotRange -> All], 
     ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I would think (having become cautious) that the integral is divergent since there is no prescription of how to circumvent the pole in the integrand at x = x0 = 1/Sqrt[1-b^2] which is > 1 for 0 < b < 1.

As it is the integrand becomes 1/(x-x0) times a finite factor so that the integral is logarithmically divergent.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My answer was wrong. Need to reconsider it. I delete my posts here and in the refenced Location.