# How to plot the result of this singular integral?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Please I open a new post here after this one : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59203/10158

Now I want to plot the function $f(a,b)$ as a function of $b$ for different values of $a$ : $a=0.5$ , $a=10$ and $a=100$

$f(a,b)=1-\dfrac{a  \, b^2}{K_{2}(a)}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\Bigg[\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\displaystyle{\int_1^{\infty }\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{\sqrt{x^2-1} (1+x\sqrt{1-b^2}) (x-1/\sqrt{1-b^2})} \, dx}\Bigg]$

where $K_{2}(a)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind and $\dfrac{\partial^2} {\partial a^2}$ is the $2^{nd}$ derivative with respect to a.

Mathematica input form:

```
1 - ((a b^2/BesselK[2, a]) D[(1/a) (1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) Integrate[E^-ax/(Sqrt[x^2 - 1] (1 + x Sqrt[1 - b^2]) (x - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2])), {x,1, Infinity}], {a, 2}])
```

how do it please?

Thank's.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: minor point but you need a space between `a x`

Comment: After recognizing an error in my previous post, I think that the expression f(a,b) is divergent. Surely, the integral is divergent because of the pole at x = 1/Sqrt[1-b^2], and because of the factor 1/a the divergence (which is independent of a) remains even after differentiating twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I assume that the OP wants to compute the Cauchy principal value of the integral, since the integrand has a simple pole in the interior of the interval of integration.  Dealing with such singularities is described in the tutorial [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#295594003).

I let the derivative be computed in the process of defining `f`.  The symbols `a` and `b` are highlighted in red by the syntax highlighter because they appear as function arguments and as symbols being blocked.  It indicates a warning of a potential scoping conflict.  But `Block` is evaluated before the definition of `f` is set, so the warning may be ignored in this case.  The differentiation results in an expression that contains a linear combination of three `NIntegrate` integrals.  I combine these, more or less manually, with pattern replacements that implement the linearity properties of the integral. This reduces computation time by about 40%.

```
ClearAll[f];

f[a_, b_] /; a > 0 && 0 < b < 1 := 
 Evaluate[Block[{a, b, NIntegrate}, 
   1 - ((a b^2/BesselK[2, a]) *
       D[(1/a) (1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) *
          NIntegrate[Exp[-a x]/(Sqrt[x^2 - 1] (1 + x Sqrt[1 - b^2]) (x - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2])),
           {x, 1, 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2], Infinity}, 
           Method -> "PrincipalValue"],
        {a, 2}]) /. 
    HoldPattern[Times[NIntegrate[int_, args__], coeff__]] :>
      NIntegrate[Times[int, coeff], args] /. 
    t : Plus[_NIntegrate, __NIntegrate] :> 
      NIntegrate[First /@ t, Sequence @@ t[[1, 2 ;;]]]
   ]]
```

For the plot, I set a few options for `NIntegrate` suitable for plotting.  Somehow some of the coefficients get set to `MachinePrecision` which causes a precision warning; therefore I turned the warning off.

```
Module[{opts = Options[NIntegrate], plot, offQ},
 SetOptions[NIntegrate, {WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 12}];
 offQ = Head[NIntegrate::precw] === $Off;
 Off[NIntegrate::precw];

 plot = Plot[
   Evaluate@Table[f[a, b], {a, {0.5`20, 10, 100}}], {b, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 12];

 SetOptions[NIntegrate, opts];
 If[! offQ, On[NIntegrate::precw]];
 plot
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Evaluation is still rather slow, the plot above taking about 28-29 seconds.